# usage of 'more common'

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

We all know that tigers are found only in Asia and not in Africa. So is it correct to say that tigers are "more common" in Asia than Africa?

Comment: If tigers are not found in Africa, then they are not common in Africa at all. So it's inappropriate to say that they are _more_ common in Asia than in Africa. Asia has tigers, and Africa does not.

Comment: [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/539954/is-the-usage-of-more-frequently-or-more-often-correct-in-this-scenario/540027#540027) to a similar question answers this one as well.

Comment: -jsw29 I read your answer to a similar question  , I understood the difference between semantics and pragmatics , but can we use these types of constructions in everyday conversations , or , will it be wrong to do so ? A highly qualified GMAT verbal expert said that these kind of constructions are fine(read 'acceptable').

Comment: Also , does infelicitous means 'wrong' or 'inappropriate' , meaning that something , even if it is 'infelicitous' can still be used ?

Comment: -jsw29 , whether pragmatics or semantics dictate whether what we are trying to convey is correct or not . As , a thing might be semantically correct , but pragmatically wrong , or vice versa .For eg- suppose a sentence is semantically(logically) correct but pragmatically odd , can we still use that sentence.?

Comment: @yaash, the answer to the linked question explains in what ways it would be wrong, and in what ways it wouldn't.

Comment: -jsw29 , will you ever use this type of construction in such a scenario given that it is semantically correct but pragmatically wrong?

Comment: @yaash, **no** (but I can't completely rule out the possibility that some highly unusual situation would arise in which it would not be infelicitous—pragmatics always involves the context).

Comment: i don't quite agree with this -jsw29 . If someone says that an event takes place more often than you think , then the person saying this ha no way of knowing  whether we think that the event takes place once or twice or more times or never . Still the listener understands what the speaker is trying to say. In the same way if I know that you think that an even never takes place but the event indeed takes place regularly , I  can without a doubt say that the event takes place more often / more frequently than you think .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the usage of "more frequently" or "more often" correct in this scenario?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/539954/is-the-usage-of-more-frequently-or-more-often-correct-in-this-scenario)

Comment: While tigers aren't currently found in Africa, some could escape from a zoo and take up residence in the wild. So it could become true. And aside from that, someone could lie. It's an odd definition of grammaticality if it involves counting tigers, which is not a skill typically taught in English or linguistics departments.

Comment: 'Tigers are more common in Asia than Africa' would default to 'There are some tigers in Africa, but there are more in Asia'. So a Gricean maxim (using language the way the vast majority do) is violated, and the statement is unacceptable (outside of a logic class, where pragmatics is often, by agreement, sidelined). // Are there no tigers in African zoos?

Answer (score 0):

If you used 'more common', I would take it to mean that tigers occur with greater frequency in Asia than Africa, but that they do also exist in Africa in some capacity. The 'more' in 'more common' is the difference between the two things being compared - more completely I would understand the sentence as:

> While tigers are common in Africa, they are **more** common in Asia

Since tigers don't live naturally in Africa (it wouldn't surprise me if some where there as pets), 'more common' is probably not the correct phrasing. Generally people would understand your point, in fact many probably incorrectly assume that tigers *do* exist in Africa anyway, but I would avoid using that phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

[If something is *common*, it is found in large numbers or it happens often.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/common)

Since tigers are *not found at all* in Africa, it is erroneous to say that *tigers are "more common" in Asia than Africa*.

Comment: Something can be more common than something else, without being common, just as something can be larger than something else without being large (rats are larger than mice, but neither are large animals).

Answer (score 0):

No. For something to be “more common”, whatever it’s being compared to must be less common, which implies they exist there, and, if what you said is true and tigers aren’t found in Africa, they don’t exist there at all. I’m not sure what the context of the original statement is, but you should say something like “tigers can be found in Asia, but not in Africa”.